# d3 barchart in jquery mobile -- why are there two checkboxes?

Tags: jquery-mobile, d3.js

I have modified [this d3 barchart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885705), which contains a very nice sorting feature, for presentation in a jquery mobile page.

I get the following horrible result, which I cannot figure out. (Please ignore the equally awful x-axis labels and the wrongly positioned title; I'll fix them later).

[image]

The checkbox in the upper left works; you check it and the bars sort. But its evil doppelganger shows up in the center. Click on the checkbox inside the chart area, and the checkmark shows up in both checkboxes, but nothing happens.

I'm mystified.

Here's the relevant html:

```
<div data-role='content' class='chart-here'>

  <input type='checkbox' name='checkbox-2a' id='checkbox-2a' />
  <label for='checkbox-2a' data-corners='true' data-shadow='false' data-iconshadow='true' data-wrapperels='span' data-icon='checkbox-on' data-theme='c' data-mini='false' class='chart1 ui-checkbox-on ui-btn ui-btn-hover-c ui-btn-corner-all ui-fullsize ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-up-c'>
    <span class='ui-btn-inner'>
            <span class='ui-btn-text'>Sort cereal by type</span>
    <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-checkbox-on ui-icon-shadow'>&nbsp;</span>
    </span>
  </label>
```

... and here's what I think is the relevant d3.js:

```
  d3.select('#checkbox-2a').on('change', change);

  var sortTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    d3.select('#checkbox-2a').property('checked', false).each(change);
  }, 1000);

  function change() {
    clearTimeout(sortTimeout);
```

... and the relevant CSS, without which the checkbox appears above the chart (where I want it) but does not work at all:

```
label.chart1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  left: 300px;
}
```

Anybody have any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting up your jQM page like this:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
     <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Header</h1> 
    </div>  
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
      <form>
          <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-2a" id="checkbox-2a">Sort cereal by type
          </label>
      </form>
      <div class="chart-here"></div>    
    </div> 
</div>
```

Then append your SVG to the DIV with `class="chart-here"`

UPDATE: Here is the script

```
$("#checkbox-2a").on("change", function(e){
  change(e);
});

  var sortTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    $("#checkbox-2a").prop( "checked", true ).checkboxradio( "refresh" ).change();
  }, 1000);

  function change() {
    clearTimeout(sortTimeout);
    var IsChecked = $("#checkbox-2a").is(":checked");
    // Copy-on-write since tweens are evaluated after a delay.
    var x0 = x.domain(data.sort(IsChecked
        ? function(a, b) { return b.frequency - a.frequency; }
        : function(a, b) { return d3.ascending(a.letter, b.letter); })
        .map(function(d) { return d.letter; }))
        .copy();
```

Comment: done, and the doppelganger is gone, and the upper-left checkbox appears nicely styled... but still no action. Inspecting the element in Developer Tools, <input> data-cacheval='true' when the box is unchecked, while <label> class='ui-checkbox-on'.

Comment: sorry -- <input> data-cacheval='FALSE' when the box is CHECKED, while <label> class='ui-checkbox-on', when d3.select('#checkbox-2a').property('checked', true).etc. When property('checked',false), it's the opposite. I got confused with all the double-negatives!

Comment: no, it only works when there are two checkboxes, or if I run the page in non-jqm html (withan ugly checkbox). Such a weird situation

Comment: @prokaryote, can you create a fiddle with the d3 and the jQM?